# Interactive filter options for views

Tags: 7, views, forms

I have setup a view with contextual filters; it works great.

Now I just need to setup a few drop downs to allow users to filter on criteria. Does the Views module support this in Drupal 7?

Should I just build a quick module using the form API, set the module to block level, and show the block above the listings?

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow your users to filter the view data by "exposing" your filters. See screenshot:

[image]